# Celery: Finding the settings that we use

Tags: celery

I have a Celery server that someone else set up, with a byzantine system to manage the configuration. I'd like to know the Cerely settings that our server uses, without looking at the code. I have an SSH connection to the Cerely server. Is there a command to get the settings from it? Doing things from a Python shell would be great too.

Comment: I tried `celery inspect conf` now, I don't know whether it's the right command. In any case it completely froze, without giving any output. After 5 minutes I pressed Ctrl-C and it exited without any error message.